# How to slice a string in a nested element inside of an array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested, slice

I need to slice a string element that is nested inside of a JSON file formatted as an array using JS.

```
"fields": {
            "title": "Jameson Library 12th Floor",
            "slug": "Jameson-12th-floor",
            "shortDescription": "[All Jameson Library Floors](/jameson-floor-maps \"All Jameson Library Floors\")",
            "building": {
```

The filteredFloors array is passed into the component as data and mapped to a table.

```
{data.map(item => (
          <tr key={item.sys.id}>
            {columns.map(column =>
              <td role='cell' key={this.createKey(item, column)}>{this.renderCell(item, column)}</td>)
```

I'm trying to return an array that omits the first 17 spaces of the title so all that remains is the floor (i.e. "12th Floor"). Any ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON array, since JSON is a text format. Evaluated as JavaScript, there are no arrays in your code.

Comment: The JSON file is formatted as an array. What you are seeing above is just a snippet that I'm trying to modify for every element that has a value for "title"

Comment: you might cause yourself trouble if there are other titles that prepend the floor number that you want by focusing on 18. is every `title` guaranteed to begin with "Jameson Library " ?

Comment: Every title begins with "Jameson Library "

Comment: Convert your JSON to an object var obj = JSON.parse(yourJson). Then access your title with obj.fields.title. Then you can just slice the title string.

Comment: Is it not possible to map over the array and slice the title in some way? It may be completely obvious, but I'm new at this.

Comment: I think it may be best to post exactly the response your getting from your API, you say a JSON array but what you have posted is just JSON.

Comment: Sorry I'm not more clear. The JSON file is an array of objects and I'm trying to filter a common property to all the objects in the array. Does that make more sense?

Comment: So again, I would convert the JSON into an Object using JSON.parse() then you can access that array and the items inside it to do your filtering. If you post the actual structure of your json including the array, I can help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're able to pull the `title` data, you can use `slice` against it.

```
// this will slice the first 16 characters and return "12th Floor"
// remember whitespace is counted, not just characters
"Jameson Library 12th Floor".slice(16);
```

Comment: Does converting it into an obj disrupt the integrity of it being an array? Really what I am trying to do is filter an array. The API is sending the data via array, which is how I need it, but I need to filter out the name from the title.

Comment: To better answer this, how are you currently accessing the data within the JSON and what are you doing with it once you have it?

Comment: The data is coming from a headless CMS (Contentful). It's loaded into a React website and set to an array called filteredFloors. I would like to filter the filteredFloors against this modification to the title. The end result will map the array to a table.

Comment: By table I am assuming you mean an html table? How do you intend to write this array into a table? This is the important part because this is where you can transform the data from within your filteredFloors array; `title`, `slug`, etc. however you'd like. You first need to be able to grab these pieces of data in order to work with them.

Comment: I have the array mapped to a HTML table already and it works fine. It uses this filteredFloors array as an input and I'm using lodash to get the items. I'd like to just replace the array that is serving as the input with a new one that has the modified title property. There are 13 objects in the array all with the same property. AllI need to do is trim the first 17 characters of the front of fields.title. I'm a novice at all this so thank you for your patience.

Comment: Of course, not a problem at all. We all start somewhere and by no means am I a professional. I just like to try and help others where I can.

I've personally never used lodash. How are you using lodash to pull the data? I found [_.pullAt](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#pullAt) which pulls data from the given index. One idea is to use this to pull your `title` data and assign it to a variable, run your `slice` against it that variable, then write that new `title` back into your filteredFloors. eg `filteredFloors[0] = title`